# Project is missing in api (hence octo.exe can't find it)

Tags: octopus-deploy

We're using octo.exe to create releases. It starts suddenly giving error saying can't find project. I checked the api/projects and that's true, it is not in the returned json response. But when I look at the dashboard I can see the project. The only thing I did was cloning another project from this one earlier. The cloned project is working fine but not the original project.

It exists in dashboard (web gui) but not in api (hence octa.exe can't find project)

Looks like api is caching the projects. The new projects that I created via GUI not available in api.

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of Octopus are you using? It might be easier to contact support for issues like this. support@octopusdeploy.com

Comment: If it's quick and easy, backup the Octopus Deploy database and recreate the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same issue yesterday. It turns out to be something interesting. I believe that your project is still there properly set, but the total number of projects that you have become more than the listed ones in the API, and that's why the Octo.exe couldn't see it anymore.

I have explained [here](https://dankovalkov.wordpress.com/2016/06/16/project-is-missing-in-the-api-octopus-deploy-octo-exe/), how I managed to fix that issue quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to how pagination is implemented in Octopus (pretty poorly if you ask me). But you can override it. add this to the URL (at the end).

```
'?skip=0&take=2147483647'
```

alternatively, you can watch the json returned, if you find the links.Page.Next property you can use that link to get next page of the api response.